# Jquery clash when together, but work independently

Tags: jquery, scroll

These two scripts work independently, but clash when used together. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!-- scroll-box ================================================== -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.scroll-follow.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function () {
        $( '#box-scroll' ).scrollFollow();
    });
</script>

<!-- button================================================== -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#check" ).button();
    $( ".category" ).buttonset();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you including 2 versions of jQuery in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is very straightforward. You only need one instance of jQuery in page. When you load the second version it overwrites the whole jQuery object and wipes out any plugins that were registered to original

Load jQuery before any plugins or dependent code.

Also... no point in loading jQueryUI core...then loading the full version after that. Pick one or the other depending on your needs

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides a solution for this issue.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script>
    myJQ = $.noConflict();
</script>
<script>
    // You should use `myJQ()` instead of `$()` from now on to use the second included jQuery:
    myJQ("#div").html("Hello!");
</script>
```

Comment: Although, in the case of this specific question one should not include jQuery again, because jQuery UI can utilize the existing, the already included jQuery library.

Comment: very rare to have a case where you need 2 versions